# Can PCs meet up with old friends and take them on as cohorts?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, npc

I'm trying to recreate a character from a video game. The only problem is that his gear is really powerful, and was provided by other people. So I've been looking for a way to recreate this in D&D. What better way than to have this character meet up with old friends who can craft the gear for him?

I'm talking about official rules (or possible homebrew) in 3.5, discussing a player choosing specific cohorts, player background implementation, etc. If it is viable, then how could it be implemented? If it isn't viable, then what are some other alternatives? The problem I'm looking to solve is that magical items are very important to my character, but he is a front-line fighter himself and not a crafter.

Comment: Quite importantly, are you the player or the GM?

Comment: Could you clarify whether you are a player or a GM in this circumstance?

Answer (score 3):

The Dungeon Master's Guide gives DMs advice on how to treat NPCs friendly to the party on page 104. It makes a distinction between Allies, Cohorts, Followers, and Hirelings.

## Allies

The DMG describes allies as:

> Those who help the PCs with information, equipment, or a place to stay the night.

The section describes an NPC, Viran Rainsong, that gives the party "great deals on potions and scrolls that she manufactures." This seems like a great fit for your idea - the character has friends in the world, and they offer him a deal on the equipment they craft. No rules are presented on players creating allies - you must go out into the world and win them over! Make sure to put ranks into your Diplomacy skill.

## Cohorts

A PC can acquire an NPC cohort by taking the Leadership feat from page 106 of the DMG. However, according to page 104, a PC can make a deal with an NPC (usually half a share of wealth from loot) in exchange for getting that NPC as a cohort, and there's no mention of Leadership being *required* for a cohort. A cohort's relationship with his leader is that of a hanger-on and follower, not friend and equal, though obviously you can roleplay it any way. If you need only one character to craft you your items, a cohort is a better way to go.

## Contacts

The DMGII gives us Contacts, found on page 153. The entire section describes rules for NPCs that perform services for the party. You can have a number of contacts equal to your Charisma bonus. The section does not explicitly mention crafting magic items, but does say that contacts will perform skill checks for you (and crafting - for mundane items, at least - is a skill check). There's no reason a contact who can craft items won't craft one for you given the materials.

## Costs of crafting

Nobody is going to give you free magic swords. You can pay an NPC the gold necessary to craft one, but it also costs them XP. Fortunately, Wizards of the Coast has provided a [free excerpt](https://web.archive.org/web/20210218011855/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20060526a) of the PHB II that covers this.

> If you are commissioning a magic item for which you are willing to transfer the XP cost, a discount of 5 gp per 1 XP is subtracted from the final market price.

The article describes three ways of doing this:

**Transference (spell)**

> This spell allows you to store a transfer of XP from one or more creatures (maximum five), but only for the purpose of constructing an agreed upon magic item.

**Talisman of Transference (magic item)**

> A talisman of transference transfers XP from the wearer to the person who constructed the magic item, so long as the magic item was made from the original raw material to which this device was linked.

**Ceremony of Transference (feat)**

> You can courier a transfer of XP from one or more creatures (maximum five) into an agreed upon magic item you are constructing.
>
> ...You can rely on any creature participating in this ritual who transferred at least 50% of the XP cost to provide prerequisite spells for the agreed upon magic item.
>
> ...Similarly, you can rely on any creature participating in this ritual who transferred at least 50% of the XP cost to provide ability score, alignment, character level, class level, class feature, race, or skill rank prerequisites for the agreed upon magic item.

---

So there you have it. Make some magic friends, inject them with your XP, and they'll make you crap.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**: Yes, if it's part of the story.

**Long Answer**: Sure, but it may be a bad idea - it may not be balanced and it may not be fun for the whole table.

In a video game (particularly an MMO), outfitting a new character is called [twinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twinking) - it's generally a way you help an RL friend get up to speed in a game you've been playing a lot longer than them. It's a **good** thing, because your new-to-the-game friend can blow through old content easier, and be able to play the same content as you sooner.

In a table-top RPG, the exact same word is used to refer to players who are looking for an unfair advantage - it's a variation of [powergaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powergaming). Unless the whole player group and the GM are into that kind of oneupsmanship, its a **bad** thing. Nobody likes feeling taken advantage of.

If you're the GM and you're introducing a powerful character that is "yours" from someplace else, you're flirting with the concept of a GMPC. While having a mouthpiece character can be useful, as a GM you have to avoid taking the spotlight off the player characters. Think of it a bit like TV - player characters are the main cast, the stars of the show. When a "special guest star" comes on, they're a big part of the plot, but the story is about how the main cast reacts to them... and they're gone the next episode.

It's a common new GM mistake to think that the party *needs* your super powerful character to do something. If they *need* some other character to follow your plot... you're narrating a book, not running a role-playing game.

Comment: It's 3.5e, so the game system is now known if you want to edit your answer.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Yeah, I've been watching. He hasn't indicated if he's the player or the GM. My original read of the question had me thinking he's the GM. The new version makes that appear less certain - he mentions "player" and "my character" a few more times, but the question has the [tag:npc] tag...

Comment: I think the [npc] tag is there because the question is asking about cohorts (which would be NPCs).

Answer (score 0):

**Magic Gear at Character Creation**

Gear has a listed cost (see Magic Items in the DMG).  Your character has an amount of starting gold depending on level.  That gold can be spent on gear even if your character cannot craft it personally.  It is assumed that he went, and bought, the gear.  From someone who can craft it.  Or found it in a tomb or whatever - WBL is not literal gold, just the total wealth in possessions, however the items were acquired.

**Cohorts**

A 'cohort' is a specific feature of the Leadership feat (and some class abilities).  They are a NPC of a specific level who nominally follows the orders of the player character.  As an NPC they are designed by and approved by the GM, but many GMs allow players to design their own cohorts and also often to roleplay as them/make combat decisions for them.

**Hireling/Ally/Whatever**

Despite some listed rules existing for wages paid to mercenaries, listed costs to buy slaves etc, typically having allies that are not explicitly granted by class abilities, feats, or gear is entirely up to the GM.  Trying to attract some mercenaries to follow you into battle is something that has enough variables that it is mediated nearly entirely by the GM, from the price to whether it is possible at all.  This includes when creating a character.

**Followers**

Are much lower level NPCs also granted by the Leadership feat.  Usually created by the GM, much less often is the player given control of these things (unlike the Cohort).

**Should the GM give you magic items and 'old friends' as free cohorts for no reason other than that you want to be overpowered.**

No.

**Should important characters to your character's backstory that are accompanying the party be played as PCs if at all.**

Yes.

**Should you not attempt to rehash a video game character in DnD because it never ends well.**

Yes.

To sum up, **if your backstory says you are a dragon king with 500 dragons and a floating sky palace and you are personal friends with Elminster, the God of Magic, and he shows up and helps you all the time, that's great.  Except that it isn't.  You don't get to actually have those things just because you wrote them in your backstory.  Your stats are your stats, your possessions are your possessions, and if your backstory doesn't jive with that, it's *your fault for having an inappropriate backstory to the power level and genre***.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** your character can meet up with old friends, but **no** you can't have them give your character free stuff.

When you create a character, that character starts with a certain amount of wealth -- generally the DM will tell you how much.  For example the DMG recommends that a second-level character starts with 900gp worth of equipment; a 10th level character starts with 49000gp.  It doesn't matter how your character got their equipment. You could narrate that it was purchased with gold, stolen, found in a dragon's hoard, inherited, or (as you propose) a gift from a friend.  What matters is that the total value of all your equipment is the right amount of wealth.

There are various things you could theoretically do with DM permission.  For example with DM permission you could take the Leadership feat when you reach sixth level, and then you could work with your DM to create stats for one of your character's friends and make them a cohort, and then with DM permission your cohort could craft magic items for you (and the rest of your group) at a discount.

It's even possible, with DM permission, for one of your character's friends to just give you a magic item during the game.

The problem you'll run into is that the DM wants to enforce party balance: the game will run better if all the characters in the party are about equally powerful.  If you try to make your character more powerful than the other characters, the DM can (and should) stop you.

I'm not sure which character you're trying to recreate, but let's talk about Batman for the moment.  Your character might not start with enough wealth to actually be Batman; if your character concept was "I am Batman" you might need to get a new character concept.  But you could reasonably tell people that you're a younger version of Batman -- you're still the same guy, but from earlier in the timeline, before he had all the best skills and equipment.  Or you could have your character concept be that your character *wants* to be Batman, but isn't quite awesome enough yet.

---

Note: all this is different if you're the DM and you're creating an NPC.  When you're the DM, you can give your NPCs whatever equipment and abilities you want -- you just have to make sure not to overshadow the player characters.  If you create a particularly powerful NPC, you need to also create a reason why that NPC can't (or won't) hang out with the party and do the quest for them.  Maybe the NPC has something else they need to be doing, or maybe they have a key weakness which means they can't go adventuring, or maybe they just don't like the player characters.